Compress directory with another name
I have this task:
- archive:
    path: ./my_dir
    dest: ./dir.zip
    format: zip

Resulting dir.zip contains a directory my_dir/. Is it possible to rename the directory when compressed so it's called "whatever/" instead of "my_dir/"?
I can't rename the original directory. I want to rename it just when it's being compressed.


Is it possible to rename the directory when compressed?

No, such is not implemented. But according the documentation Examples, a minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - archive:
      path: test/*
      dest: test.zip
      format: zip

will result into a ZIP files with content of
unzip -t test.zip
Archive:  test.zip
    testing: folder/one               OK
    testing: folder/two               OK
    testing: folder/three             OK
    testing: one                      OK
    testing: three                    OK
    testing: two                      OK
No errors detected in compressed data of test.zip.

Means, creating an archive of a globbed path will leave out the unwanted directory name and provide the opportunity to specify an other directory during extraction.
